# How to get user claims after signin through SignInManager in ASP .NET CORE Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP .NET Core 2.0 project in which I am using Microsoft's Identity framework for authentication/authorization. I have the following method that validates the user against username and password and returns claims count. The user I am trying to login is found in database but it's claims are being returned 0 here - in the database the claims do exist against the user (see the image[image]).

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] LoginDto model)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = _signInManager.UserManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Email == model.Email);
            var userClaims = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(appUser); // this is returning 0 claims

            return Ok(HttpContext.User.Claims.Count());
        }

       throw new ApplicationException("INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT");
    }
```

The answers on the possible duplicate question did not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that *both* `userClaims.Count()` and `HttpContext.User.Claims.Count()` return 0?

Comment: Yes I have checked both - they are both 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Identity Role, Claim and User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024218/asp-net-core-identity-role-claim-and-user)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `UserManager.GetClaimsAsync`, it will query claims from `AspNetUserClaims` instead of `AspNetUserRoles`. You could check this by [GetClaimsAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/EF/UserStore.cs#L439)

```
return await UserClaims.Where(uc => uc.UserId.Equals(user.Id)).Select(c => c.ToClaim()).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

In general, we could try `HttpContext.User.Claims` to retrive the claims for the user, but it will work for sub-request instead of current login request. If you move this `HttpContext.User.Claims` to `Home` `Index` action, it will return the expected result.

For getting claims in `Login`, I suggest you try

```
                var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(appUser);
                var claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();
```